# return called before onPageFinished

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I have a WebView I use for some simple web scraping, which works fine but when I put it in a function and try to return whatever it scraped the return part is called before the WebView even scraped. How can I make it wait before calling return, since a return inside onPageFinished isn't possible?

```
fun loadText() : String {
        myWebView2 = findViewById(R.id.webView2)
        var stringToBeReturned = ""
        myWebView2.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView2.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                super.onPageFinished(myWebView2, url)
                myWebView2.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();") { value ->
                    stringToBeReturned = value.substringAfter("on \\u003C/span>\\u003Ca href=\\\"").substringBefore('\\')
                }
            }
        }
        myWebView2.loadUrl("https://www.examplewebsite.com")

        return stringToBeReturned
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPageFinished()` is a callback, that gets called asynchronously (whenever the page has been loaded) **after** your function returns.

You should not have this callback in a function. Instead do the configuration in `onCreate()`, set the Callback and pass the `resultString`, once its available, wherever you need it:

```kotlin
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView2)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                // this function gets called as soon the page has been loaded
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();") { value ->
                    val resultString = value.substringAfter("on \\u003C/span>\\u003Ca href=\\\"").substringBefore('\\')
                    // pass resultString wherever you need it
                }
            }
    }
  }
```